# Spring Boot application with part of JSP files from other Maven module

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Let's assume that we have Spring Boot based web application using JSP templates. It can be even as simple as in the following example (from official [Spring Projects repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp))

Project structure:

```
|-src/main/java/
|    |-sample.tomcat.jsp
|        |-SampleTomcatJspApplication.java
|        |-WelcomeController.java
|-src/main/resources/
|    |-application.properties
|-src/test/java/
|    |-...
|-src/main/webapp/
|    |-WEB-INF
|        |-jsp
|            |-welcome.jsp
|-pom.xml
```

Properties file contains view prefix `/WEB-INF/jsp/` and suffix `.jsp` and when requesting `/` we see properly rendered content of `welcome.jsp`.

[WelcomeController.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src/main/java/sample/jsp/WelcomeController.java)

[application.properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src/main/resources/application.properties)

**Changes**

Now let's make the following changes

1. Duplicate `WelcomeController.java` as `WelcomeController2.java` and change a bit request mapping, model attributes and returned view name, e.g.:

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/2")
   public String welcome2(Map<String, Object> model) {
       model.put("message", "Hi from Welcome2");
       return "welcome2";
   }
   ```
2. Duplicate `welcome.jsp` as `welcome2.jsp` so that `src/main/webapp` will be like this:

   ```
   |-src/main/java/
   |    |-sample.tomcat.jsp
   |        |-SampleTomcatJspApplication.java
   |        |-WelcomeController.java
   |        |-WelcomeController2.java
   ...
   |-src/main/webapp/
   |    |-WEB-INF
   |        |-jsp
   |            |-welcome.jsp
   |            |-welcome2.jsp
   ```

Then when requesting `/2` we can see properly rendered content of `welcome2.jsp`.

**The question**

What is the way of splitting such project into two maven projects, so that both `WelcomeController2.java` and `welcome2.jsp` could be moved to other project (maven dependency) and still be successfully resolved when `/2` URL is requested?

Note that with Spring Boot `web-fragment.xml` (that could be placed in `META-INF` directory of dependency) is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know of an easy way to do this but one approach I've used is to create a Maven artifact just like normal for the main project, in your case probably a WAR artifact.  This project will need to have a dependency upon your second project.  Then your second project would consist of two components:

1. A standard Maven JAR artifact containing the compiled class files.
2. A [Maven assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-assembly-plugin-2.5.4/) ZIP consisting of the JSP files that need to be included in the WAR archive as well.  This will be generated from the second project during the `package` phase, but will need to be included as a separate dependency on the main project using a `zip` classifier.

When the first project is built, you'll need to [unpack the assembly dependency](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html) as part of the packaging process for the WAR archive.  If you want this to work in an IDE, you'll probably need to unpack it in a fairly early phase, such as `process-resources` or `generate-sources`.